# Get last column of string without AWK

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I was wondering if I could use `sed` or `grep` (but no `-P` flag) to give the same functionality as `awk '{print $6}'`.

I am making a script for iOS, but I don't want to have to install any 3rd party commands (like `awk`).

- The `grep` on iOS also doesn't support the `-P` flag, so no `perl-regexp`.
- `cut` is a 3rd-party command on iOS (so no `cut`)

Answer (score 6):

If you have a string in a *variable* in a script and you'd like to extract the last field (as you say in the title of the question), then you may do

```
field=${string##* }
```

This assumes that the string in `$string` is space-separated (change the space in the above variable substitution to whatever delimiter you're using). The `${variable##pattern}` variable substitution removes the longest prefix string from `$variable` that is matching the given `pattern`.

With `sed` on a file, the following would extract the last whitespace-separated field of each line:

```
sed 's/^.*[[:space:]]//' data.in
```

It does this by deleting everything up to and including the last whitespace character on each line.  Change `[[:space:]]` to a regular expression that matches the delimiter before the last column if your data does not use tabs or spaces as delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your answer works on Linux, but `cut` is a 3rd party command on iOS. +1 anyway :)

Comment: @JacobCollins See the edited version by the author. Also, note that first solution (`${variable##* }` part) involves  shell operation that is specified by POSIX standard, which in other words means it should work pretty much anywhere, including iOS.

Answer (score 2):

With `grep`, assuming `-o` option is available (also, going by title that last column is needed, not just particular column)

```
$ echo 'foo bar 123' | grep -o '[^ ]*$'
123
$ echo 'foo;bar;123' | grep -o '[^;]*$'
123
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the last blank-delimited column with a POSIX compliant `sed` (the equivalent of `awk '{print $NF}'`) and assuming the input is valid text:

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]*$//; # remove trailing blanks
     s/.*[[:blank:]]//; # remove every thing up to the last blank
    ' < file
```

Note that most `awk` implementations separate fields on blanks (horizontal spacing), but some (namely busybox `awk`) separate on all spaces (`[[:space:]]`), and some only on the ASCII blanks (space and tab) regardless of the locale. On files coming from Microsoft OSes, you may want to replace `[[:blank:]]` with `[[:space:]]` so it considers the trailing CR character as spacing and discards it.

To get the sixth field (equivalent of `awk '{print $6}'`):

```
s='[[:blank:]]' S='[^[:blank:]]'
sed "s/^$s*\($S\{1,\}$s\{1,\}\)\{5\}\($S\{1,\}\).*/\2/; t
     s/.*//; # flush the line if does not have 6 fields"
```

You could also use an approach like:

```
sed 's/[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}/\
&\
/6; s/.*\n\(.*\)\n.*/\1/;t
s/.*//'
```

Answer (score 0):

One could do something like this:

```
$ var="This is a string"; printf "%s\n" $var | { while read -r line; do  last="$line"; done; printf "%s\n" "$last"; }
string
```

This takes advantage of word-splitting and `printf`'s ability to keep fitting arguments to format string even if their number doesn't match. That allows us to transform each word or field of string into separate lines. That is coupled with standard `while read -r variable; do...done` loop for 
reading `stdin` stream line by line, where we just get last line, aka last field.

This is whole lot of acrobatics but it is a shell approach that doesn't rely on external tools. However for *really* portable and proper shell-only way,  [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421962/85039) is still better.

Comment: That assumes `$var` doesn't contain wildcards and that `$IFS` has not been modified.

Comment: Or use a bash array (with same caveats about IFS and glob) `a=($var); printf '%s\n' ${a[${#a[@]}-1]}` (or in _recent_ bash just `${a[-1]}`) or if you don't need to preserve positional params or else localize them with a function or subshell `set -- $var; printf '%s\n' ${!#}` or in poorer shells `... shift $(( $#-1 )); printf '%s\n' "$1"` or yuckily `... eval printf '%s\\n' \"\${$#}\"`

Answer (score 0):

I tested for below case  with space delimitter to print last column using sed command and it worked fine

```
input.txt

praveen ajay abhi
```

Method1

```
echo "praveen ajay abhi"| sed -r "s/.* //g"
```

output

abhi

Comment: `-r` is a GNU extension and is not needed here. On BSDs, `-E` is more common to enable extended regular expressions. The `g`  flag is also superfluous as the regex can only match once here (assuming valid text input). Note that like many other answers here, it doesn't work on the output of `echo " first  second  last "` (with more blanks after the last field)